# Removing AVAudioPlayerNode after use causes crash

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

I'm using `AVAudioEngine`to play sound files and record the output to a file. I have lots of sound effect files, each played by tapping a button. To play the file I create an `AVAudioPlayerNode` and connects it to the engine. After the file has played I try to disconnect/detach the node in the completionHandler closure, to free up memory. If I don't remove nodes I will just keep adding new nodes and new connections to the engine.

However, the next time I try to play a file, the app just freezes. Here's my code:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(name, withExtension: "wav")!
let audioPlayerFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
self.engine.attachNode(playerNode)
self.engine.connect(playerNode, to: self.engine.mainMixerNode, format: audioPlayerFile.processingFormat)
playerNode.scheduleFile(audioPlayerFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
    self.engine.disconnectNodeOutput(playerNode)
    self.engine.detachNode(playerNode)
})
playerNode.play()
```

What's the best way to implement a functionality like this, i.e. playing multiple files, potentially overlapping each other, while recording?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem. I've found that detaching the node on a background thread keeps the app from freezing.

```
    playerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, atTime: nil, options: nil) { () -> Void in
        self.detach(playerNode)
    }
```

And here's the method:

```
    func detach(player: AVAudioPlayerNode) {
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) { () -> Void in
            self.engine.detachNode(player)
    }
```

However, I'm still unsure this is a solution per se, because these background threads might be spinning infinitely without my knowledge.